# Bootstrap dynamic Modal can't find jquery for second time

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am loading bootstrap modal dialog through ajax. For the first call, it goes through fine but in subsequent calls, it starts giving error that it can't find jquery.

Parent page has jquery, bootstrap libraries and modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="profile_Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="profileModalLabel"
 aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

In this page, I have a section included through ajax call. This section has a link to load modal in #profile_Modal and also the ajax call for loading modal dialog. This section has bootstrap libraries included again.

```
$('.action-icon .edit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = some url;
        $('#profile_Modal').load(url, function () {
            jQuery.noConflict();
            $('#profile_Modal').modal('show');
        });
    });
```

The included code snippet is like this with only required libraries like autoresize.jquery.min.js, jquery.form.js and jquery.validate.min.js

```
<div class="modal-dialog" id="book_review_dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="booReviewModalLabel">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Write Review</h4>
    </div>
    <form id="save_review_form" method="post" action="some url">
        <div class="modal-body">
          ....
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" >
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Not Now</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-continue">Save</button>
        </div>in
    </form>
</div>
```

The error that I am getting in subsequent calls are that it can't recognize libraries like

```
TypeError: $(...).autoResize is not a function
* jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0
```

I am using jquery 2.1.1 and bootstrap 3.1.0

Comment: Not sure if this fixes the issue, but I notice you have a possible syntax error. `$('.action-icon .edit'')` looks like it should be `$('.action-icon .edit')`. There's an extra `'` near the end of the jQuery selector.

Comment: Hey @Shoreline ,sorry about that, it was a typo in question here. Corrected it. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: "This section has bootstrap libraries included again." Don't do that! It's not meant to be loaded multiple times.

Comment: Thanks @cvrebert ! I removed it but still no luck